# handle a object that can return null in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

```
Android Studio 3.0
```

I am have java code that I am converting to Kotlin for my project.

```
public String getAuthUserEmail() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String email = null;
        if (user != null) {
            email = user.getEmail();
        }
        return email;
}
```

I have converted it to koklin like this:

```
   fun getAuthUserEmail(): String? {
        val user: FirebaseUser? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        return user?.email
    }
```

I am just wondering in my kotlin version if the user happens to be null. Should I need to have an if condition to check if the user is null?

I could have the function as a one line

```
   fun getAuthUserEmail(): String? {
       return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.email?
    }
```

And would the calling function need to handle a null string that could be return from the function?

Many thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I need to have an if condition to check if the user is null?

According to Firebase's doc:

> Returns the currently signed-in FirebaseUser or null if there is none.
>
> Use getCurrentUser() != null to check if a user is signed in.

So, it depends on how you want to handle when there is no signed-in user.

If you want the function to be one-lined, you can chain it like this:

```
fun getAuthUserEmail(): String? {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.email
}
```

It will return null if `currentUser` is null or `currentUser?.email` is null.

---

Edit: If you simply want to return email if it exists. It's ok to write it in one line, since [safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) can be chained.

Answer (score 1):

Small advice. If you are sure object shouldn't be null, but is nullable, use `!!` to mark object as one that shouldn't be null. If app crashes it is okay as it shows you that u did somewhere bad implementation. Look at the structure of your implementation to know wheter object should be null or not, a lot of devs overuse `objet?.let` without looking if this object should be null or not

Answer (score 1):

> I am just wondering in my kotlin version if the user happens to be
>   null. Should I need to have an if condition to check if the user is
>   null?

Depend on the case how you are going to handle scenario but you can form 
your data in [Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) way as below:

```
fun getAuthUserEmail(): String? {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.email ? "No data"
}
```